# MLeap problem: Impossible to deserialize a bundle written with Scikit-Learn with Pyspark. Error: No bundle.json found

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mleap

I serialize a model with Scikit-Learn:

```
#Generate data
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 5), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
df["y"] = (df['a'] > 0.5).astype(int)
df.head()

from mleap.sklearn.ensemble.forest import RandomForestClassifier

forestModel = RandomForestClassifier()
forestModel.mlinit(input_features='a',
                   feature_names='a',
                           prediction_column='e_binary')


forestModel.fit(df[['a']], df[['y']])

forestModel.serialize_to_bundle("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/mleaptestmodelforest", "model.json")
```

When I try to read it with Pyspark:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassificationModel

model = RandomForestClassificationModel.deserializeFromBundle("file:/dbfs/FileStore/tables/mleaptestmodelforest")
```

I have this error:
`java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /dbfs/FileStore/tables/mleaptestmodelforest/bundle.json`

I have no "bundle.json".

Could you help me please?
Is it really possible to seralize a model with Scikit-Learn and deserialize it with Pyspark?